# Help to understand "the short trip saw ..."

Tags: word-usage

> The short trip saw a North Korean train enter China on Monday but was otherwise cloaked in secrecy.

I saw this sentence in a Yahoo news. The part I am confused is **The short trip saw**. How come a trip could possibly see something? In my opinion, only a person or animal can really see something. Can someone help me to understand? Thanks!

[The full context](https://www.yahoo.com/news/latest-convoy-seen-beijing-arriving-train-station-072033506.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is meant in this sense:

> **see** *v.tr.*
>   5.
>   b. To be characterized by; be the time for: "*The 1930s saw the development of sulfa drugs and penicillin*" (Gregg Easterbrook).
>   c. To be subjected to; undergo: *This word sees a lot of use in sports*.

[From The Free Dictionary Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/see)

Here is the sense of your sentence:

> The short trip featured a North Korean train entering China but was otherwise cloaked in secrecy.

Comment: I can't find this usage in my dictionary. Is it common? I haven't seen the usage before.

Comment: @dan: I added a link to it. And yes, it is commonplace.

Comment: what does it mean in this context then? Could you explain it in more detail for this particular context? Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've spelled it out for you now.

Comment: According to this dictionary https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see, the usage is defined in British. Is it regional?

Comment: It's actually quite standard. Something you see in journalism, history books, etc.